# Stability of superoxides of alkali metals

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Why are superoxide ions stable only in presence of large cations such as $\ce{K}$, $\ce{Rb}$ and $\ce{Cs}$?

Comment: I think it has a lot to with the heat of formation/..; See this link for some research on lithium superoxide: http://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcontrails.iit.edu%2FDigitalCollection%2F1965%2FAMRLTR65-126.pdf&ei=tbb3UvTsLKPy7AaTt4HoCA&usg=AFQjCNEJ5yK3cTwESsuGx4Ds9b0zFbvu9A&sig2=Y-W2XUhH1vBWnTPSJaQgSQ&bvm=bv.60983673,d.ZGU&cad=rja

Answer (score 6):

According to the Wikipedia page [Alkali metal oxides](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkali_metal_oxide), the superoxide of $\ce{K}$, $\ce{Rb}$ and $\ce{Cs}$ form when these metals are burnt in air, and according to the Bodner Research Group page [Active Metal Reactions](http://chemed.chem.purdue.edu/genchem/topicreview/bp/ch9/active.php), they

> **react so rapidly with oxygen** they form superoxides, in which the alkali metal reacts with $\ce{O2}$ in a 1:1 mole ratio.

Given, according to the Chem-Guide blog article [Alkali metals](http://chem-guide.blogspot.com.au/2010/04/alkali-metals.html) that

> The fact that a small cation can stabilize a small anion and a large cation can stabilize a large anion explains the formation and stability of these oxides.

Which, according to the blog, results in the  $\ce{Li+}$ ion (which is small, possessing a larger positive field around it) only being able to naturally combine with a small anion $\ce{O^{2-}}$ forming $\ce{Li2O}$, whereas the substantially larger $\ce{K+}$, $\ce{Rb+}$ and $\ce{Cs+}$ have weaker positive fields and can stabilise the larger superoxide anion $\ce{O2^{-}}$ forming superoxides.

Comment: This is hardly an explanation; I don't why how this is the accepted answer. Stating a general rule from some blog is not the same as an intuitive reason, which is what the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

The word "stability" itself isn't very clear, so you have to figure out exactly what it is stable with respect to. If you look up the data, the reaction

$$\ce{NaO2 (s) -> Na(s) + O2(g)}$$

is not enthalpically favourable. So, $\ce{NaO2}$ is actually stable with respect to decomposition to the constituent elements.

Instead, it is actually likely to be unstable with respect to decomposition to the oxide/peroxide. Since sodium is known to burn in oxygen to form the peroxide, this hints that we should be looking at the energetics of the reaction

$$\ce{2NaO2 (s) -> Na2O2 (s) + O2 (g)} \qquad \Delta H_1$$
$$\ce{2CsO2 (s) -> Cs2O2 (s) + O2 (g)} \qquad \Delta H_2$$

If cesium superoxide is "stable" in this respect, then we would expect $\Delta H_2 > 0$. And if sodium superoxide is "unstable" in this respect, then we would expect $\Delta H_1 < 0$.

The controlling factor here is likely to be the lattice energies (which are directly related to the size of the cation). Using the Kapustinskii equation we have

$$\Delta H_\mathrm{L}(\ce{M2O2}) \propto \frac{3\cdot 1\cdot 2}{r_\ce{M} + r_\ce{O2}} = \frac{6}{r}$$

and

$$\Delta H_\mathrm{L}(\ce{MO2}) \propto \frac{2 \cdot 1 \cdot 1}{r_\ce{M} + r_\ce{O2}} = \frac{2}{r}$$

where $r = r_\ce{M} + r_\ce{O2}$ (I have assumed the radii of the superoxide and peroxide ions to be the same). In the enthalpies of the decomposition reactions above $\Delta H_i$ ($i = 1,2$), the lattice energy contribution is

$$\begin{align}
\Delta H_i &= 2\Delta H_\mathrm{L}(\ce{MO2}) - \Delta H_\mathrm{L}(\ce{M2O2}) + \cdots \\
&= 2\left(\frac{2}{r}\right) - \frac{6}{r} + \cdots \\
&= -\frac{2}{r} + \cdots
\end{align}$$

Sodium is smaller than cesium, and therefore we expect the value of $r$ to be smaller. This clearly translates into a more negative value of $\Delta H$, as expected.

Why should $\Delta H_2$ be positive, then? It is to do with the other $\cdots$ terms that were omitted. These terms basically involve the production of $\ce{O2^2- + O2}$ from $\ce{2O2-}$, which is enthalpically unfavourable and hence have a positive contribution to the enthalpy of reaction.

In the case of sodium, the $-2/r$ term is large enough to outweigh this positive term. In the case of cesium, it isn't.

---

Looking to other aspects of inorganic chemistry one might recall that carbonates of heavier alkaline earths are more stable than carbonates of light alkaline earths (e.g. $\ce{MgCO3}$ vs $\ce{BaCO3}$). The reaction $\ce{MCO3 -> MO + CO2}$ can be treated very similarly and the same conclusion will be reached.

The thermodynamics of the alkali metal oxides/peroxides/superoxides is treated more thoroughly in the following question: [Why do the alkali metals form different products upon combustion in air?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/50796/why-do-the-alkali-metals-form-different-products-upon-combustion-in-air)

Answer (score 0):

Well according to my book 'General and inorganic chemistry volume 2, by Dr. Ivan Filipovic & Dr. Stjepan Lipanovic ', the oxidation state of superoxides is **-1/2**. $\ce{K}$, $\ce{Rb}$ and $\ce{Cs}$ react with oxygen and form type $\ce{MO2}$ compounds called superoxides. They are ionic crystalised compounds containing cation $\ce{M+}$ and anion $\ce{O^2-}$, and since the oxygen anion has 13 valent electrons, superoxides are colorful, paramagnetic, and **unstable** compounds, and they also exist only in solid state.